# Which of these scenarios is faster for retrieving a formatted date?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I have a DATETIME string and I need only the DATE in my script to perform some searches in my database. Currently, I have two scenarios in my mind, but don't know which of them is faster.

**The first scenario:**

In my MYSQL database, I have two columns: `datetime` (which is a DATETIME type) and `date` (which is a DATE type).

Then, in my PHP script, each time I save a record, I will insert my known string to the `datetime` field, and then convert it to fit the `date` field (I was thinking of something like: `$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datetime))`).

This way, all the necessary pieces are stored in my database and I can retrieve them on the fly (both the `datetime` and the `date` fields).

**The second scenario:**

The MYSQL database should consist only of the `datetime` column.

My PHP script will insert the known string to the `datetime` field without any other modifications.

And when I retrieve my data, I would do something like: `SELECT datetime, DATE(datetime) FROM ...`

**Conclusion**

Which of these scenarios is faster and therefore should be used? Should date formats be made on save or on retrieve? Is MYSQL faster than PHP on formatting dates? Is it better to store everything in the database and retrieve as it is, or store only the minimum and format on retrieve? Which of these scenarios is the best practice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of your usecases:

If you are only going to need the `date` for reading, then go with a single `datetime` column, conversion from `datetime` to `date` is cheap enough.

If you are going to select rows at a given date (like `WHERE date = '2011-08-01'`), then go for a `date` column, as this will allow mysql to use the indexes on the `date` column if you have added one.

If you are going to select rows in a date range, then go for a `datetime` column. You could do things like `WHERE datetime >= '2011-08-01' AND datetime < '2011-08-16'`.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is the best and fast as you are getting the value based on the requirement. Rather getting some value and working on it later.

Answer (score 1):

*imho*

- datetime, or even unsigned integer (unix timestamp) is better for range filtering
- datetime allow date-time function, it could be useful for aggregate function
- avoid formatted data from mysql (that's mean raw)
- anything related to presentation is PHP duty

Comment: So, you suggest I have only the `datetime` column in my database, and retrieve the `date` in PHP, using the retrieved `datetime`?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely depends on your situation - if you will be reading (a lot) more than writing, you can store both. But I'd go for storing one field (datetime) and convert that, either in PHP or while retrieving it from MySQL (convert datetime to char in the format you like)